# Why are char << and char >> intermediate results int

Tags: c++

cygwin gcc 4.5.3

I am trying to determine the intermediate results used in various computations in C++. For 'char' I get the follwoing results (x is a char):

```
x op y is of type char if y is a char/unsigned char
x op y is of type y otherwise except if op is left/right shift
```

For left/right shifts, the intermediate result is of type 'int', which is contrary to all other computations. Is this the standard implementation?

Here is the code used (don't get too excited by it):

```
# include <iostream>
# include <iomanip>
# include <typeinfo>
# include "cstdio"
# include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char  UCHAR;
typedef unsigned short USHORT;
typedef unsigned int   INT;
typedef unsigned long  ULONG;
string find(type_info* info) {
   struct type {
      type_info* typeInfo;
      string     name;
   };
   int i;
   static type types[] = { {const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(bool)),   " BOOL"  }
                         , {const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(char)),   " CHAR"  }
                         , {const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(UCHAR)),  " UCHAR" }
                         , {const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(short)),  " SHORT" }
                         , {const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(USHORT)), " USHORT"}
                         , {const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(int)),    " INT"   }
                         , {const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(uint)),   " UINT"  }
                         , {const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(long)),   " LONG"  }
                         , {const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(ULONG)),  " ULONG" }
                         };
   for(i = 0; i < sizeof(types)/sizeof(types[0]); i++ )
      if (types[i].typeInfo == info) break;
   if (i >= sizeof(types)/sizeof(types[0])) return " NOT FOUND";
   return types[i].name;
}
void func0(char x) {
   ios_base::fmtflags ioFlags = cout.flags();
   string info = find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x)));
   char save = x;
   cout << "func0(char " << (long)x << ')' << endl;
   cout << "!x  " << setw(12) << (!x)    << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (!x) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(!x))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "~x  " << setw(12) << (~x)    << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (~x) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(~x))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "+x  " << setw(12) << (+x)    << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (+x) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(+x))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "-x  " << setw(12) << (-x)    << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (-x) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(-x))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "++x " << setw(12) << (long)(++x)    << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (++x) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(++x))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' '); x = save;
   cout << "--x " << setw(12) << (long)(--x)    << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (--x) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(--x))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' '); x = save;
   cout << "x++ " << setw(12) << (long)(x++)    << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x++) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x++))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' '); x = save;
   cout << "x-- " << setw(12) << (long)(x--)    << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x--) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x--))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << endl;

}
void func1(char x, char y) {
   ios_base::fmtflags ioFlags = cout.flags();
   cout << "func1(char " << (signed long)x << ", char " << (unsigned long)y << ')' << endl;
   cout << "x  + y " << setw(12) << (x  + y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  + y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x + y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  - y " << setw(12) << (x  - y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  - y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x - y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  * y " << setw(12) << (x  * y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  * y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x * y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   if (y == 0) {
        cout << "x  / y " << x << " / 0" <<  endl;
   } else {
        cout << "x  / y " << setw(12) << (x  / y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x / y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x / y))) << endl;
   }
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x %  y " << setw(12) << (x  & y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  & y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x  & y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x << y " << setw(12) << (x << y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x << y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x << y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x >> y " << setw(12) << (x >> y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x >> y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x >> y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  & y " << setw(12) << (x  & y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  & y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x  & y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  | y " << setw(12) << (x  | y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  | y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x  | y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  ^ x " << setw(12) << (x  ^ y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  ^ y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x  ^ y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << endl;
}
void func1(char x, unsigned char y) {
   ios_base::fmtflags ioFlags = cout.flags();
   cout << "func1(char " << (signed long)x << ", uchar " << (unsigned long)y << ')' << endl;
   cout << "x  + y " << setw(12) << (x  + y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  + y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x + y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  - y " << setw(12) << (x  - y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  - y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x - y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  * y " << setw(12) << (x  * y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  * y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x * y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   if (y == 0) {
        cout << "x  / y " << x << " / 0" <<  endl;
   } else {
        cout << "x  / y " << setw(12) << (x  / y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x / y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x / y))) << endl;
   }
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x %  y " << setw(12) << (x  & y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  & y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x  & y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x << y " << setw(12) << (x << y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x << y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x << y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x >> y " << setw(12) << (x >> y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x >> y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x >> y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  & y " << setw(12) << (x  & y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  & y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x  & y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  | y " << setw(12) << (x  | y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  | y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x  | y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  ^ x " << setw(12) << (x  ^ y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  ^ y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x  ^ y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << endl;
}
void func1(char x, unsigned long y) {
   ios_base::fmtflags ioFlags = cout.flags();
   cout << "func1(char " << (signed long)x << ", ulong " << y << ')' << endl;
   cout << "x  + y " << setw(12) << (x  + y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  + y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x + y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  - y " << setw(12) << (x  - y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  - y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x - y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  * y " << setw(12) << (x  * y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  * y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x * y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   if (y == 0) {
        cout << "x  / y " << x << " / 0" <<  endl;
   } else {
        cout << "x  / y " << setw(12) << (x  / y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x / y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x / y))) << endl;
   }
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x %  y " << setw(12) << (x  & y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  & y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x  & y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x << y " << setw(12) << (x << y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x << y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x << y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x >> y " << setw(12) << (x >> y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x >> y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x >> y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  & y " << setw(12) << (x  & y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  & y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x  & y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  | y " << setw(12) << (x  | y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  | y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x  | y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  ^ x " << setw(12) << (x  ^ y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  ^ y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x  ^ y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << endl;
}
void func1(char x, long y) {
   ios_base::fmtflags ioFlags = cout.flags();
   cout << "func1(char " << (signed long)x << ", long " << y << ')' << endl;
   cout << "x  + y " << setw(12) << (x  + y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  + y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x + y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  - y " << setw(12) << (x  - y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  - y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x - y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  * y " << setw(12) << (x  * y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  * y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x * y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   if (y == 0) {
        cout << "x  / y " << x << " / 0" <<  endl;
   } else {
        cout << "x  / y " << setw(12) << (x  / y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x / y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x / y))) << endl;
   }
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x %  y " << setw(12) << (x  & y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  & y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x  & y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x << y " << setw(12) << (x << y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x << y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x << y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x >> y " << setw(12) << (x >> y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x >> y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x >> y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  & y " << setw(12) << (x  & y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  & y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x  & y))) << endl;
cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  | y " << setw(12) << (x  | y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  | y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x  | y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << "x  ^ x " << setw(12) << (x  ^ y) << " 0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << (x  ^ y) <<  find(const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(x  ^ y))) << endl;
   cout.flags(ioFlags); cout << setfill(' ');
   cout << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   char x = -1;
   func0((char) 1);

   func1(x, (char) 1);
   func1(x, (unsigned char) 1);
   func1(x, (long) 1);
   func1(x, (unsigned long) 1);
   sleep(1);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get result type `int` for all `char/[unsigned] char` operations, as it should be (integer promotions).

Answer (score 1):

Your initial conclusions are incorrect. All arithmetic operations in C/C++ perform the computations within the domain of size `int` at least (or, maybe, `unsigned int`). All smaller operand types (`char`, `short` etc.) are promoted to `int` before any actual computations begin and the result has type `int`. Only operations like prefix and postfix versions of `++` and `--` preserve the type of their operand.

That applies to operations like binary `+`, `*`, `-` etc. That applies to `<<` and `>>` as well. So `<<` and `>>` are in no way different from other arithmetic operators.

How did you manage to conclude that `"x op y is of type char if y is a char/unsigned char"` is not immediately clear to me. I just ran your code and it confirmed the expected behavior: only operations like `++` and `--` evaluate to `char` type, while all other operations on `char` arguments evaluate to `int` values.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf: Yes. I added that "at least" to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I am using cygwin gcc 4.5.3. I trust your comments. I'm not sure I trust my code, but the upshot is that the expected results are not what I see. I don't know why there is a difference. I looked at the 'offending' statements in my code and they appear to be correct, or at least the same as other statements.

Answer (score 0):

After making the code compile by adding the following at the top,

```
typedef unsigned uint; //!
void sleep( int ) {} //!
#include <string> //!
```

there is still some formal UB, but shouldn't really matter.

The results do *not*, however, indicate that

> “x op y is of type char if y is a char/unsigned char
>   x op y is of type y otherwise except if op is left/right shift”

What compiler are you using?

You ask,

> “Is this the standard implementation?”

Well, no, there is no standard implementation. There's only an ISO standard.

Comment: @AudreyT: I am using cygwin gcc 4.5.3 as my compiler. My results are different from yours and are, hopefully, given below. Forgive my imprecision in asking for a 'standard implementation', I did mean an implementation according to the ISO standard. Here are my results:
func1(char -1, long 1)
x  + y            0 0x00000000 LONG
x  - y           -2 0xfffffffe LONG
x  * y           -1 0xffffffff LONG
x  / y           -1 0xffffffff LONG
x %  y            1 0x00000001 LONG
x << y           -2 0xfffffffe INT
x >> y           -1 0xffffffff INT